# Rcpp - sum() in lapply()

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm practicing Rcpp and have found that there are some very useful functions called 'sugar functions' available that behave just like the counterparts defined under the same names in R. One of the functions that I very frequently use is lapply(), and with a slight tweak in the provided function in 3.2.3. seq_len in a reference I found (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf), I could make it work seamlessly. The codes I wrote in the stand-alone C++ file, which is sourced through sourceCpp(), look as below. The function that vector x is applied to is seq_len().

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_lapply_function()
{
  IntegerVector x = seq_len(10);
  List y = lapply(x, seq_len);
  
  return(y);
}
```

However, when I replace seq_len() in lapply() with another basic function, such as sum() and mean(), the compilation fails with an error. I'm not knowledgeable in C++, so it makes me unsure why this happens even after searching through online hours. I would really appreciate any feedback and a solution to make it work.

For clarification, below are the codes that failed in compilation with sum() and the error message says, no matching function for call to 'lapply(Rcpp::IntegerVector&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_lapply_function()
{
  IntegerVector x = seq_len(10);
  List y = lapply(x, sum);
  
  return(y);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- and to Rcpp / C++.  As a statically typed language you cannot always drop a function in place of another. `seq_len` fits the required signature for `lapply` but `sum` does not.  Note that `seq_len`  returns a vector for a scalar argument where as `sum` takes a vector and returns a scalar.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, `@Dirk`. I've tried `NumericMatrix` or `DataFrame` for `x`, but the compilation still failed with the same error message. Is this because `lapply` converts the input on the first argument to a vector and then passes it as scalars, to which function is applied each? If so, is there a way to pass a vector instead of a scalar?

Comment: Sure. You can use many Rcpp functions on many Rcpp objects.  But you cannot "randomly" jam them into `lapply` which after all is merely a somewhat efficient loop handler. I would step back and try simple (and explicit) transformations on your data structures. In other words, walk a list or vector ... element by element, ensure you get correct expected values (_i.e._: print them to screen), then transform and get them back.  Remember that compiled loops are fast so don't force yourself into a `lapply`-shaped corner.

Comment: Sure. You can use many Rcpp functions on many Rcpp objects.  But you cannot "randomly" jam them into `lapply` which after all is merely a somewhat efficient loop handler. I would step back and try simple (and explicit) transformations on your data structures. In other words, walk a list or vector ... element by element, ensure you get correct expected values (_i.e._: print them to screen), then transform and get them back.  Remember that compiled loops are fast so don't force yourself into a `lapply`-shaped corner.